# Read specific columns starting from certain rows from excel file using readxl package in R

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I'm trying to read an excel file into R.  I need to read column A and column C (no B), starting from row 5.  Here is what I did:

```
library(readxl)

read_excel('./data/temp.xlsx',  skip=5,
            range=cell_cols(c('A', 'C')))
```

The code above does not work. First, it does not skip 5 rows. It reads from first row. Secondly, it also read column B, which I do not want.

Does anyone know what I did wrong? I know how to specify the cell range, but how should I pick the specific columns I need?

Comment: Import it all and drop them later …Do also check some of the documentation eg regarding skip 
… 
Minimum number of rows to skip before reading anything, be it column names or data. Leading empty rows are automatically skipped, so this is a lower bound. Ignored if range is given.

Comment: the excel file is large. I need a way to read just a couple on columns

Comment: So after the skip comment - Have you tried supplying the columns in a more Excel-ish format?
Example shows: 
read_excel(datasets, range = cell_cols("B:D")) 
Notice the absence of skip plus the absence of c() so maybe give "A;C" (or comma instead of semi-colon depending on your language settings) a shot! I ain't no readxl pro/user

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `column_types` argument (check `?read_excel`) to skip columns from being read. For instance, if columns A and C are numeric:

```
readxl::read_excel("/path/to/data.xlsx", 
    col_names = FALSE, 
    skip = 5, 
    col_types=c("numeric", "skip", "numeric"))
```

NB: if the column types are unknown initially you could read them as text and convert them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the content from [readxl.tidyverse.org](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/sheet-geometry.html#range). One of your questions regarding why column B is also added is because:

```r
## columns only
read_excel(..., range = cell_cols(1:26))
## is equivalent to all of these
read_excel(..., range = cell_cols(c(1, 26)))
read_excel(..., range = cell_cols("A:Z"))
read_excel(..., range = cell_cols(LETTERS))
read_excel(..., range = cell_cols(c("A", "Z"))
```

Hence, `cell_cols("A:C")` is equivalent to `cell_cols(c("A", "C"))`

Previously, what I did was in one of my projects was the following. I guess you can adapt the following and extract the data by column, then join them together.

```r
ranges = list("A5:H18", "A28:H39", "A50:H61")

extracted <- lapply(ranges, function(each_range){
                read_excel(filepath, sheet = 1, range = each_range, na = c("", "-"), col_names = cname, col_types = ctype)
        }) %>%
                reduce(full_join)
```

Regarding your question about skipping rows, I'm also not sure because I was also searching for this answer, and found your question on stackoverflow.

**[edit]** I think I found some readings on https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/577. Anyway, if you use `range`, you can't do any `skip`, as `range` takes precedence over `skip` and others